# Shake form on screen

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, system.drawing

I would like to 'shake' my winforms form to provide user feedback, much like the effect used on a lot of mobile OS's.

I can obviously set the location of the window and go back and forth with `Form1.Location.X` etc. but the effect from this method is terrible. I'd like something a little more fluent - or alternatively is there a way to shake the entire screen?

I'll only be targeting Windows 7 using .net 4.5.

**Update**

Using both Hans and Vidstige suggestions I've come up with the following, which also works when the window is maximized - I wish I could pick two answers, I've up-voted your answer though Vidstige and hope others will too. Hans' answer hits all the salient points though.

Two forms `MainForm` and `ShakeForm`

### MainForm Code

```
 Private Sub shakeScreenFeedback()

        Dim f As New Shakefrm
        Dim b As New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

        Me.DrawToBitmap(b, Me.DisplayRectangle)

        f.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        f.Width = Me.Width
        f.Height = Me.Height
        f.ShowInTaskbar = False

        f.BackgroundImage = b
        f.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center
        f.Show(Me)
        f.Location = New Drawing.Point(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y)

        'I found putting the shake code in the formLoad event didn't work
        f.shake()
        f.Close()

        b.Dispose()

    End Sub
```

### ShakeForm Code

```
Public Sub shake()
    Dim original = Location
    Dim rnd = New Random(1337)
    Const shake_amplitude As Integer = 10
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        Location = New Point(original.X + rnd.[Next](-shake_amplitude, shake_amplitude), original.Y + rnd.[Next](-shake_amplitude, shake_amplitude))
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20)
    Next
    Location = original

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean with fluent? A shake is typically not very fluent...

Comment: as I understand fluent means smooth and animated.

Comment: yes, and how does a fluent shake look like? A shake to me would be a quite erratic and rapid movement.

Comment: For want of a better word - I'd like to shake the active window and for it not to look like an animation from a ZX Spectrum. In before 16/48k or 128k.

Comment: @GJKH nice that you solved it! answer given in collaboration are the best answers :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The typical problem is having way too many controls on the form, making the painting too slow.  So just fake it, create a borderless window that displays a bitmap of the form and shake that one.  Create the bitmap with the form's DrawToBitmap() method.  Use 32bppPArgb for the pixel format, it draws ten times faster than all the other ones.

Comment: I've had a look at your suggestion, I can get the bitmap but I'm struggling with what to do with it afterwards - how do I display it and how would I use 32bppPArgb as you recommend? Sorry, not done a lot of work with graphics. Also would I have to hide and then display the main form while doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Just overlap the form with your new one, Show(owner) overload.  Dispose it again when you're done shaking.

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried something like this?

```
    private void shakeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Shake(this);
    }

    private static void Shake(Form form)
    {
        var original = form.Location;
        var rnd = new Random(1337);
        const int shake_amplitude = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            form.Location = new Point(original.X + rnd.Next(-shake_amplitude, shake_amplitude), original.Y + rnd.Next(-shake_amplitude, shake_amplitude));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
        form.Location = original;
    }
```

Comment: Oooh...the effect of this is actually what I'm after, unfortunately it doesn't work when the window is maximized.

Comment: How could it possibly work when the window is maximized? Where would it shake to? Off of the screen? You could write the code to do that, but I've never seen that on either OS X or any mobile devices. It would just be weird.

Comment: sliding off to UX here, but I think it could be a quite cool effect. It could also be really annoying depnding on how itäs used. It would definately get the users attention.

Comment: With the approach I used above the effect not only works when the window is maximized but is also really effective. The app I've developed forces a user to stay within certain inputs until the data they have entered is valid and had complaints that this confused people. The shake effect certainly grabs their attention. I agree it could be annoying though so I've used it sparingly. To be fair I'd find a popup box far more annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Aero Shake feature of Windows 7 to achieve this.

Better you can have a look in the below link for more details:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36294/Aero-Shake

Comment: I think @GJKH is asking how to make the form oscillate as a visual cue, whereas your answer is telling him how to detect when the user grabs the form and shakes it.

Comment: @Dommer is correct, I'm looking to provide a visual cue to the user. Also I thought all apps in windows 7 had this feature by default? Just tested my app and it responds to shaking by minimizing all open windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small work around, you may try it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width = this.Width - 10;
        this.Height = this.Height - 10;
        Thread.Sleep(15);
        this.Width = this.Width + 10;
        this.Height = this.Height + 10;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this but this is akin to me moving the location of the form by its X,Y location as I stated above - the effect is undesirable, it looks like something is broken/loading rather than the app providing feedback.